# Regarding mailing ascii images -php

Tags: php, html

How do i send an ascii image via mail in php?   Had used the link https://github.com/idevelop/ascii-camera to create the ascii image from the camera.  When I  send it in a mail it's not showing the image but displaying ascii characters.  I tried contenttype text/plain charset ascii  and text/html but don't get the photo in the email. Could anyone help me out. Thanks.

Pasted the php code below

```
<?php
$headers = 'From: webmaster@test.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: webmaster@test.com' . "\r\n" .
               'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"  . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$to='testmail@test.com';
$subject='from camera with image mod';
$message=$_POST["msgbody"];
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: You should use **monospace** font for image to reveal in email. Otherwise it will be a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **monospace** font for image to reveal in email. Otherwise it will be a mess, bec. character width is different if font is not fixed width.

---

Try this as body text:

```
$body = "
<html>
    <body>
        <pre style='font: monospace'>".$_POST["msgbody"]."</pre>
    </body>
</html>";
```

Content type should be `Content-type: text/html;`.

---

<kbd>!</kbd> Direct use (*without sanitize*) of user entered data is **very insecure**.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the info. will get back to you after testing.

Comment: Thanks a  lot.  It works.  How do i give multiple font-family  font-family: 'Courier New', 'Courier', monospace;   in inline css style.  Currently I have  <pre id='ascii' style='font-family:Courier New;font-size: 10px;line-height:10px;letter-spacing:-1.5px;text-align:center;'>".$_POST["msgbody"]."</pre>